# Wordpress rest api not displaying pages when domain name updated

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

So I've been sort of racking my brain on this topic, and every resource I find doesn't exactly hit the nail on the head for me.

The problem is, I'm helping someone who is hosting a site in an AWS EC2 instance that uses a WordPress REST API for specific pages on the website, there are other pages which are static that are stored in an S3 bucket. When he goes to update the domain name from the Amazon URL to "something.com" that points to the Amazon URL, the pages using the API no longer display but instead come up as an error, but when he clicks the links for the static pages, they work fine.

If there's any clarification needed, please let me know, I'm sure its become confusing.

Comment: You need to be more specific. Show the steps you followed when attempting to change the domain, and clarify how WordPress and S3 are being used/setup in your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this might be due to the [same-origin policy](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com/how.html). The browser thinks that the domain from which the script is loaded into the browser (`something.com`) is different from the domain on which the WordPress endpoints live (S3 bucket, `s3.amazonaws.com`). Check the developer console if it says something like `Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for the pages using the API.